# Why is Fermi level the same in p type and n-type semi-conductor when they are connected?

Tags: electrons, semiconductor-physics, fermi-energy

In an energy band diagram the Fermi energy for both p-type and n-type are the same. Shouldn't the Fermi level be higher in the n-type because it holds the 5th electron very loosely therefore having greater energy?

Comment: If they are connected than equilibrium requires that the Fermi levels are the same.